# Changing the order of elements in a chart legend

Tags: plotting, legending

In a stacked `BarChart` or `Histogram` the bars are stacked from bottom to top, while the legend entries are listed from top to bottom. Is there a way to make the legend entries go the other way round to improve the visual correspondence between the chart and the legend?

E.g.

```
{bottom,middle,top}=RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0,1],{3,200}];
Histogram[{bottom,middle,top},10,ChartLayout->"Stacked",ChartLegends->{"Bottom","Middle","Top"}]
```

[image: histogram]

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/q/7786778/353410

Comment: [also](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7477278/499167)  related?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7074209/499167) question might also be of interest

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Histogram[{bottom, middle, top}, 10, 
          ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
          ChartLegends -> {"Bottom", "Middle", "Top"}] /. 
Column[l_List] :> Column[Reverse@l]
```

[image]

Comment: Slick answer! +1

Comment: I just checked out that linked question. That's also a really slick answer!

Comment: This is great, thanks. It seems so obvious now!

Comment: @SimonWoods It is not obvious at all if you don't run Histogram[...]//FullForm first :)

Answer (score 11):

Using belisarius' method, if you want to reverse the order for all vertical legends you could use [`` Legending`LegendContainer ``](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080536/618728) like this:

```
{bottom, middle, top} = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {3, 200}];

SetOptions[Legending`GridLegend, 
  Legending`LegendContainer -> (Framed[# /. Column[l_List] :> Column[Reverse@l]] &)
];

Histogram[{bottom, middle, top}, 10,
  ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
  ChartLegends -> {"Bottom", "Middle", "Top"}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: **Legending** sounds like a pejorative adjective for the works of people like JK Rowling

Comment: @belisarius you always find something to make me laugh. :D

Answer (score 7):

This solution will no longer work in Mathematica 9 because they now use SwatchLegend in FullForm. Instead, apply this:

```
Histogram[{bottom, middle, top}, 10, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
ChartLegends -> {"Bottom", "Middle", "Top"}] /. 
SwatchLegend[l1_List, l2_List, r1_Rule, r2_Rule] :> 
SwatchLegend[Reverse[l1, 1], Reverse[l2, 1], r1, r2]
```

The integer parameter in `Reverse[l1,1]` and `Reverse[l2,1]` might have to be tweaked; in some cases I had to reverse within the second level instead of the first. //FullForm should give you enough hints.

Comment: Where can I learn more about this type of syntax, eg. the l1_List and ri_Rule stuff?  I'm not exactly sure how this is working, nor do I know how to use FullForm to help figure this out.  I'm trying to flip a legend on a ListLogLogPlot using SwatchLegend.

Comment: Ah, I got it!  Seems a regular Plot only has one Rule following the two List elements in the FullForm of SwatchLegend.  Removing r2_Rule and r2 in the delayed replacement does the trick.

Comment: Yea that is exactly right.

Answer (score 6):

belisarius beat me to the `Column` replacement rule method.
An alternative method would be to use `ShowLegend` to construct the legend manually, taking the code for the layout from the `FullForm` of your original graphic. The ridiculously complex lokking color specifications happen to be the Mathematica defaults for bar charts.

```
ShowLegend[ Histogram[{bottom, middle, top}, 10,  ChartLayout -> "Stacked"], 
 {{{Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.9], 
      Directive[GrayLevel[0.85], EdgeForm[Opacity[0.7]], Opacity[0.5],
        RGBColor[0.6, 0.5470136627990908, 0.24]], 
      Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]}, {ImageSize -> 10}], 
    "Top"}, {Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.9], 
      Directive[GrayLevel[0.85], EdgeForm[Opacity[0.7]], Opacity[0.5],
        RGBColor[0.6, 0.24, 0.4428931686004542]], 
      Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]}, {ImageSize -> 10}], 
    "Middle"}, {Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.9], 
      Directive[GrayLevel[0.85], EdgeForm[Opacity[0.7]], Opacity[0.5],
        RGBColor[0.2472, 0.24, 0.6]], 
      Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]}, {ImageSize -> 10}], "Bottom"}}, 
  LegendPosition -> {0.25, 0.2}, LegendBackground -> White, 
  LegendBorder -> None, LegendShadow -> None, 
  LegendSize -> {0.6, 0.35}, LegendBorder -> None, 
  LegendTextSpace -> 3}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out, [Belisarius' method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4579/52) no longer works on v9.  But, there are built in tools that do not require [additional manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17776/52) to work. [`LineLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LineLegend.html), [`PointLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PointLegend.html), and [`SwatchLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SwatchLegend.html) all accept the form

```
LegendFunction[{lbl1, lbl2, ...}, options]
```

where `{lbl1, lbl2, ...}` are the legend labels, and the legend function will pick up the styles of the chart/plot automatically.  This also works with `Automatic` and `"Expressions"`, where appropriate. The key here is that the three legends can be then interchanged at will, and additional options can be supplied to change how they are displayed.  In this case, the option you are looking for is `LegendLayout`, specifically, "ReversedColumn":

```
Histogram[{bottom, middle, top}, 10, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 ChartLegends -> 
  SwatchLegend[{"Bottom", "Middle", "Top"}, 
   LegendLayout -> "ReversedColumn"
  ]
]
```

[image]

Or, if you are curious

[image]