# BarChart with BarOrigin->Left: axis on top

Tags: visualization, plotting

This question is somewhat related to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4576/changing-the-order-of-elements-in-a-chart-legend) one.

Let's say this is the `BarChart` i want to make:

```
BarChart[Range[5], ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", BarOrigin -> Left,
 ChartLegends -> Map[ToString, Range[5]]]
```

[image: BarChart reflected]

The `BarChart` runs from the bottom and the legend starts at the top. The related question (linked above) gives a solution to reverse the legend, but i'd rather have the axis (and thus the purple bar) on top. It should look like this (made with `ImageReflect[]`):

[image: BarChart reflected]

I tried `AxesOrigin`, but that doesn't work. My question seems pretty trivial, but i haven´t found a solution for it yet.

**Question: is there a way to specify the origin of a `BarChart`?**

Comment: @PlatoManiac: why did you delete your solution? I was about to accept it...

Comment: @A.Goossens please consider waiting longer before Accepting an answer.  I recommend 24 hours to allow people in all time zones a chance to answer.  You'll almost always get better answer this way (versus the quick Accept).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: i will wait a bit longer the next time. On the other hand, encouraging quick answering by accepting a good one isn't bad either. ;)

Comment: I think people already answer as quickly as they can.  I urge you to reconsider your practice.  At least be willing to change your Accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple of options:

```
data = Reverse @ Range[5];

BarChart[data,
  ChartStyle -> "Rainbow",
  BarOrigin -> Left, 
  Frame -> {False, False, True, False}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {None, All}},
  ChartLegends -> data
] /. x_Column :> Reverse /@ x
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Manual coloring for reverse gradient:

```
colors = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ 
  Reverse @ FindDivisions[{0, 1}, Length@data - 1];

BarChart[data,
  ChartStyle -> colors,
  BarOrigin -> Left,
  Frame -> {False, False, True, False},
  FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {None, All}},
  ChartLegends -> data
] /. x_Column :> Reverse /@ x
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Minor variation on @Mr Wizards answer:

1. using {{l,r},{b,t}} syntax for `Frame` just to be consistent with `FrameTicks`
2. using `ColorFunction` to alter the colour ordering

gives

```
BarChart[Reverse@Range[5],
 BarOrigin -> Left,
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"],
 Frame -> {{False, False}, {False, True}},
 FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {None, All}}]
```

[image]

```
BarChart[Reverse@Range[5],
 BarOrigin -> Left,
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", "Reverse"}],
 Frame -> {{False, False}, {False, True}},
 FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {None, All}}]
```

[image]

Note that you could have also used `ColorFunction -> Function[{x},ColorData["Rainbow"][1-x]]`.

Now for the legends. Unfortunately the legends are based on `ChartStyle` so when you control the bar colours using `ColorFunction` the `ChartLegends` option doesn't work (in so far as no color swatches are produced).

[image]

This does not present a problem for this case -- which seems to be the specific example you are looking for:

```
BarChart[Reverse@Range[5],
 BarOrigin -> Left,
 ChartStyle -> "Rainbow",
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"],
 ChartLegends -> Map[ToString, Range[5]],
 Frame -> {{False, False}, {False, True}},
 FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {None, All}}]
```

[image]

but for other variations this simple code doesn't produce ideal outcomes:

```
BarChart[Reverse@Range[5],
 BarOrigin -> Left,
 ChartStyle -> "Rainbow",
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", "Reverse"}],
 ChartLegends -> Map[ToString, Reverse@Range[5]],
 Frame -> {{False, False}, {False, True}},
 FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {None, All}}]
```

[image]

It seems clear that the built in legend option should base its colour swatches on the actual colours used to render the bars (i.e. in this case controlled by `ColorFunction`). That it does not seems like an oversight. Most of us here don't like (understatement) the built in legends and legend options and tend to roll our own.

**Edit -- making a simple legend for your bar chart**

To reproduce the sort of legend generated with `ChartLegends` you can use `MapIndexed`

```
labels = Range[5];

Framed@Grid[
  MapIndexed[{Graphics[{ColorData[{"Rainbow", "Reverse"}][
        Rescale[First[#2], {1, Length[labels]}]], Rectangle[]}, 
      AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 15], #1} &, labels],
  Alignment -> {Center, Center}]
```

[image]

For the `ColorData` gradient to work you need to scale the argument. Within the `BarChart` `ColorFunctionScaling` by default is `True` so this happens automatically. But to get it to work here you have to do the scaling yourself -- which is what `Rescale[First[#2], {1, Length[labels]}]` is doing. You can add styling to this legend to suit whatever font choice and size you like. If you want a border around the color swatch add `EdgeForm` in the `Graphics` list. To position the legend try using `Labeled`.

```
Labeled[(*your bar chart*), (*your legend*), {{Right, Center}}]
```

Comment: Another "Why didn't I think of that?" moment. :-) +1

Comment: @Mike_Honeychurch: Thanks! Can you recommend an alternative legend package?

Comment: I'll add an edit with a simple work around legend but @Jens has posted a nice legend package on here if you do a search you will find it. ...note that doing the `x_Column :> Reverse /@ x` rule replacement as per @Mr. Wizards answer fixes the legend in the final example.

Comment: I was referring to your comment that most mma users tend to use other way to make a legend. I already fixed mine using your and @Mr.Wizard's answers!

Comment: @A.Goossens have a look at Jens package ..also the legend code above. If you're like me you'll find that you always want to tweek legends so it is worth getting familiar with how to make your own.