# Can I change Legend text in a stylesheet?

Tags: legending, stylesheet

I prefer a sans serif font in graphics, which I do by creating a style for "Graphics" in a stylesheet. However, this does not affect the style used by legend labels:

```
Plot[{x, 2x}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {"Times", "New Roman"}]
```

[image]

Is there any way to change the legend text style in the stylesheet, or can it only be done through the `LabelStyle` option?

Comment: In prior versions legending was handled by a series of accessible functions that could be modified, e.g. [(4586)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4586) -- have you done any "spelunking" in v9(+) to see what might be done?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I had a look but couldn't see where the explicit font setting was applied. I think it must be somewhere in `MakeBoxes`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me the answer is no. If you look at the box structure your plot creates, you will see it handles the legend with `TemplateBox`.

> If the tag of the TemplateBox is a string, then that style will be used for the TemplateBox.

The problem is that these `TemplateBox` instances specify the `DisplayFunction` explicitly, which will override a stylesheet.

**EDIT** (Per OP's comment.)

However, to the extent that a `DisplayFunction` does not contradict the stylesheet specifications, those specifications will apparently persist. In this case, then, the problem is that the `DisplayFunction` specifies the `FontFamily`, which will always trump the stylesheet.

Comment: For me the `TemplateBox` tag **is** a string, so I tried creating a named style for LineLegend. It turns out the legend *will* pick up the font size, weight and colour from the stylesheet but *not* the font family. Looking at the boxes, the Times font is explicitly specified in a StyleBox which overrides the style from the stylesheet :-( So I think you are right, I will have to set the `LabelStyle` option in the kernel.

Comment: @SimonWoods Oops, I get a string tag too. I was thinking in kernel mode (i.e., should be `"\"LineLegend\""`); glad you caught that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Plot[{x, 2 x}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {Style["Times", FontFamily -> "Times"], Style["New Roman", FontFamily -> "New Roman"]}]
```

[image]